# How to add Google Calendar Dynamically to jQuery FullCalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have seen how to add google calendar, but when I run it, it create's a new calendar, even though the selector I am using, refer's to an existing calendar.

```
        $calendar.fullCalendar({
        events: $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed($feed_url.val())
    });
```

I have other functions, that use renderEvents, but I am not sure how to use that with google calendars...

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thank You.

Comment: how are you setting $feed_url.val()? is it something like `var feedurl = $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed("http://www.domain.com/json-events.php?blah=20");` Where does this line go? i get errors no matter where i put within my code. cheers. I've tried before `$(document).ready(function() {`, after `$(document).ready(function() {` within `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({` etc Or is it actually a php variable and its just a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [addEventSource](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/addEventSource/) function.  If you can call that function with your `$.fullCalendar.gcalFeed($feed_url.val())` as the second argument.  I tested it over at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwheV/).

Comment: But if I am going to be able to remove these dynamically, and style them, I need to add a class, and have an id associated with the event, how do i do that?

Comment: You can still use the second parameter of the `gcalFeed` function to pass your options including className, editable, and currentTimezone.